# Finding how far between 2 numbers another number is.

Tags: calculus

I'm sorry if this comes across as a little confusing. I'm not particularly well versed in mathematical language. I'll try to use examples as I go along for clarification.

I have a table that looks like so:

```
column A column B
________|________
|2      |1234
|2.5    |2345
|3      |3456
|3.5    |4567
|4      |5678
|4.5    |6789
```

1. I am given a number $x$ which I need to use to find the row above and below it (e.g if $x=3.75$, we would use row $3.5$ and row $4$).
2. I then need to find how far $x$ is between these two numbers, we will call this result $y$ (e.g $3.75$ is halfway between $3.5$ and $4$ so $y$ woulds be $0.5$).
3. I then need to use $y$ to find the same ratio between the figures in column B to get value $z$ (e.g with our ratio of $0.5$ between $4567$ and $5678$ in this example, $z$ would be $5122.5$ as that is half way between the two).

I can get $z$ if given $y$, but I am having a problem with step 2. How would I solve for $z$ if $x$ was $2.87$ for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is linear interpolation.  See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation

x = 2.87

plug in the table values from column x0 = 2.5, x1 = 3, y0 = 2345, y1 = 3456